# Using filter() on a mapped array of objects but with omitting the data used for filtering

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have the following mapped array of objects on which I'm Using `filter()`. It is a list of TO DO tasks, from which I want to filter out only tasks that **haven't been done yet**, but without the `false` value indicating they haven't been done yet). In other words, I just want to display the tasks themselves, if indeed, they weren't done yet.

The purpose of the code is learning on a good way to omit that data (`false`) declaration from the filtered content.

```
let todos = [
    {
        todo: 'Buy apples',
        done: false
    },
    {
        todo: 'Wash car',
        done: true
    },
    {
        todo: 'Write web app',
        done: false
    },
    {
        todo: 'Read MDN page on JavaScript arrays',
        done: true
    },
    {
        todo: 'Call mom',
        done: false
    }
];
```

I tried:

```
unfinishedTasks = todos.map( (e)=> e).filter( (e)=> e.done == false);
```

as well as:

```
unfinishedTasks = todos.filter( (e)=> e).map( (e)=> if ( e.done == false ) {e.todo} );
```

The first outputs basically correct - the false todo's are there, but with the `false` keyword near them - the keyword I'd like to omit, of course:

> [{"todo":"Buy apples","done":false},{"todo":"Write web app","done":false},{"todo":"Call mom","done":false}]

The second outputs:

> Unexpected token "if".

What I desire (ommiting the `false` keyword from the output):

> ["Buy apples", "Write web app", "Call mom"]

I run the code in [teamtreehouse.com](http://teamtreehouse.com) execution snippet. To test it there, one must be a registered Treehouse student.

I might need to use another `filter()` on the filtered content, or using some `if-than` statement? I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by `item.done`, then map to `item.todo`:

```js
const todos = [{ todo: 'Buy apples', done: false }, { todo: 'Wash car', done: true }, { todo: 'Write web app', done: false }, { todo: 'Read MDN page on JavaScript arrays', done: true }, { todo: 'Call mom', done: false } ];

const out = todos
  .filter(item => !item.done)
  .map(item => item.todo);

console.log(out); // ["Buy apples", "Write web app", "Call mom"]
```